# c# xamarin Android, tcp connection problem, I can send data but I don't receive

Tags: tcp

I am writing an android application where the client must send and receive strings from a server, I can send but when the server sends the tcplistner response to the client on the phone it does not receive. On the local network everything is ok, the problem is when the client IP is the public one. Is there any procedure for mobile port forwarding? i tried to use port 80 and 443 but I get the access denied error.
some suggestions?

Comment: What exactly gives the access denied error? If there’s a TCP connection that can send data one way there shouldn’t be any “access denied”

Comment: if i use port 80 or 443 i've access denied error, if i use another port ex 1503 the client on the phone not receive the string from the server.

Comment: If i work inside local net all work fine, my problem Is that the android client not receive the data when the connection Isn't local. How can i solve this?  Is like of i Need to do Port forwarding for my phone, if Is this how can i do this programmaticaly?

Comment: Are you connecting from server to client or client to server? There’s very little information here to say anything

Comment: i have to send data from pc server to phone client but the phone client not listen.

Comment: I have no problems if both devices are on the local network and I have no problems sending data from the client running on my phone to the server on the pc even when the client is connected to the 3G network but the problem is that in this situation the client is not receiving data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by replacing tcpclient and tcplistener objects with sockets, and now communication works in both directions smoothly.